# HOw to Force Chrome browser (Citrix receiver) to use citrix server network?

Tags: google-chrome, citrix, citrix-access-gateway

I am new for citix receiver. I have citrix receiver & server.

Scenario::
Chrome browser (possible to create shortcut in receiver or integrate) is working with receiver. So it should use server side network interface to access internet (But not local network interface).
Please suggest, how to achieve this.

I have gone through with Citrix virtual channel SDK. But couldnt get the help much..

Comment: Please provide any suggestion for above problem.